# Ошибка "+" operator undefined при складывании двух Number

Tags: java

Есть класс `Box`:

```
public class Box<T extends Number> {
    private T item;

    public T getItem() {
        return item;
    }

    public void setItem(T e) {
        item = e;
    }
}
```

И основной класс:

```
public class Main {
    public static Number sum(Box<? extends Number> a1, Box<? extends Number> a2) {
        return a1.getItem() + a2.getItem();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Box<Integer> box = new Box<Integer>();
        box.setItem(5);
        Box<Double> boxDouble = new Box<Double>();
        boxDouble.setItem(5.0);
        sum(box, boxDouble);
    }
}
```

По какой-то причине в методе `sum` не хотят складываться переменные. Пишет что оператор "+" undefined.

Почему происходит ошибка? Я же просто складываю в данном случае `Double` и `Integer`.

Comment: Потому что java не складывает Number-ы? + определён для примитивных числовых типов и для строк. И вроде всё. Number не примитив и не строка.

Comment: Спасибо. Я просто сейчас смотрю онлайн-уроки по Java и парень написал такой код. Он правда объясняет, что данная запись Box<? extends Number> называется wildcard и она позволяет запихнуть туда любой класс, который наследуется от Number. Я то запихиваю туда Integer и Double. Но я так понимаю, что ошибка возникает до того, как компилятор вообще узнаёт, что я туда пытаюсь запихнуть?

Comment: Компилятор не знает что реально в боксах. Для него это нечто, являющееся Number-ом, который он не умеет складывать плюсом. напишите `a1.getItem().doubleValue() + a2.getItem().doubleValue()`

Comment: Я вас понял. Благодарю!

Comment: @Sergey, в ответ бы это написать)